# How to import my own private facebook photos to my website?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I searched internet for hours and I couldn't figure out a simple way to do this ...
My goal is to let everyone who access my website see all my own facebook photos **(so I will be using my own user id , not the logged in user)** . I don't like to use **Embedded Posts** because I want photos to be synced with my own personal facebook photos every time a user refreshes the page...

So do I need to give my facebook app full permission to access my own profile so it can retrieve all my data without asking for login ?

one more thing , I'm really confused about where facebook permissions are stored in ? and how they work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the Graph API to read the photos, this is the API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/photos#Reading

You need a User Token for that, an Extended User Token is valid for 60 days and you need to refresh it manually every 2 months.

More information about Access Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for answering :) , that's exactly what I tried to do , the problem is it returns an error because I don't have access token ... The question is how can I give the app full permission to my profile forever ?

Comment: that´s not possible. i will add more information to my answer.

Comment: Well , that looks more complicated than I thought ... so what if I use php to save the User Token into my Database and it will be updated every month using cron job. I know this sounds stupid, I couldn't figure out how to set an User Token in javascript without going through a login process ?

Comment: as i said, you need to refresh the token manually. you can´t do that with a cron job. that wold make it pointless to use tokens that are only valid for a short time.

Comment: and you MUST use a login process to get a user token. but you don´t need to program anything for that, you can use the api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Thank you so much , your answer was very clear :) , I appreciate it .